# How to move selected edges toward 3D cursor?

Tags: modeling

I know that i can set Pivot point to the 3d cursor mode on the tool bar, and then scale selected edges, and edges will be scaled towards the 3d cursor. But how to move the edges to the cursor without scaling?
[image: example]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

select your faces, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then select "selection to cursor (offset)".
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Bithur! Your approach works great, but what if i want to move my faces not complete to cursor position, but little forward, or little back, how can i do this?

Comment: move your cursor a little forward or back. In the case of your screenshot, you could move your faces along their normals with Alt+S or select the transform orientation as "normal" and use G, Z, Z